# Add Day and Time parts to a Date Object

Tags: java

I have two date objects.

```
Date d1;
Date d2;
```

My program stores in d1, the date in the format 'dd/MM/yyyy' and in d2 in the format 'HH:mm'.
I would now like to combine these information and create a new Date object with the format 'dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm'.

Any pointers on how can I achieve so?

-V

Comment: Random guess: Can't you just add both?

Comment: Pointer -> *writeSomeCode and then callSO(code,"stuckAt");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are indeed using Date objects, just set the time of d1 to match that of d2.

```
d1.setHours(d2.getHours());
d1.setMinutes(d2.getMinutes());
```

Or make a new Date object if you don't want to use d1. Just parse it afterwards with SimpleDateFormat.

Note however that this is deprecated and it's better to use Calendar for this.

Answer (score 0):

First, most of functionality of `Date` is deprecated. Use `Calendar` instead. Second, to parse and create string representation of date use `SimpleDateFormat`.

I hope these tips are enough to start. There are a lot of references in net and javadoc to continue. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use Date for this purpose. You should instead use Calendar (from JDK) or joda-time.

Comment: It can if you're happy to call deprecated methods. Otherwise, you should use Calendar.

Answer (score 0):

try out this..

```
   String dateValue= new java.util.Date().toString();
```

String concat like this..

```
   String newDateTime = d1+""+d2+":00";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    DateFormat df1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
    DateFormat df2=new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
    Date d1=df1.parse("09/07/2013");
    Date d2=df2.parse("14:43");
    String d=df1.format(d1).toString()+" "+df2.format(d2).toString();
    DateFormat newDate=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");
    System.out.println(newDate.format(newDate.parse(d)));
```